# Flink CEP select() function is not working properly

Tags: java, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I am trying to develop a simple monitoring process with the CEP Flink library. I produce a `csv` file from Kafka and I consume it with Flink and it will be a Tuple4.

Until here everything works fine. Flink consumer can perfectly consume the data from Kafka and convert it into a Tuple4. Then I create the Pattern, the PatternStream and finally the select() function for the Datastream object.

Apparently all is OK, but it doesn't work. Something is wrong with the select() function.

I also create a POJO to receive the final values. I add both codes. Thanks.

```
public class LTMonitoringTest {
private static final int LEUKO = 3500;

public static void main(final String[] ARGS) throws Exception{
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000);



    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(ARGS);

    DataStreamSource<String> myConsumer = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>
            (parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(),
                    parameterTool.getProperties()));


    DataStream<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>> streamTuple = myConsumer
            .map(new csv2Tuple())
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new ExtractTimestamp());

    streamTuple.print();

    Pattern<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>, ?> warningPattern =
            Pattern.<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>>
            begin("first")
            .where(new IterativeCondition<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter(Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long> value,
                                      Context<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>> ctx)
                        throws Exception {
                    return value.f1 <= LEUKO;
                }
            });

    PatternStream<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>> tempPatternStream = CEP.pattern(
            streamTuple.keyBy(0),
            warningPattern);


    DataStream<Warning> warnings1 = tempPatternStream.select(
            (Map<String, List<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>>> pattern) -> {
                Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long> first =
                        (Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>) pattern.get("first").get(0);

                return new Warning(first.f0, first.f1);
            }
    );

    warnings1.print();
    env.execute("CEP monitoring job");
}

private static class ExtractTimestamp extends
        AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>> {

    @Override
    public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long> element) {
        return element.f3;
    }
}


public static class csv2Tuple implements MapFunction<String,
        Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long>> {
    @Override
    public Tuple4<Integer, Integer, Integer, Long> map(String str) {
        String[] temp = str.split(",");
        return new Tuple4<>(
                Integer.parseInt(temp[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(temp[1]),
                Integer.parseInt(temp[2]),
                Long.parseLong(temp[3]));

    }

}
```

}

It receives as argumments (for kafka konsumer):

> --topic lt-monitoring --bootstrap.servers localhost:9092 --zookeeper.connect localhost:2181 --group.id myGroup

And the POJO:

```
public class Warning {

private int ID;
private int Level;

public Warning(int ID, int Level) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Level = Level;
}


/**
 * Sets new ID.
 *
 * @param ID New value of ID.
 */
public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

/**
 * Gets ID.
 *
 * @return Value of ID.
 */
public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

/**
 * Gets Level.
 *
 * @return Value of Level.
 */
public int getLevel() {
    return Level;
}

/**
 * Sets new Level.
 *
 * @param Level New value of Level.
 */
public void setLevel(int Level) {
    this.Level = Level;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Warning) {
        Warning other = (Warning) obj;

        return ID == other.ID && Level == other.Level;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 41 * ID + Double.hashCode(Level);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Warning{" +
            "ID=" + ID + getID() +
            ", Level=" + Level +
            '}';
}
```

}

So please any thought why it doesn't run?

This is the error by the way:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getUnaryOperatorReturnType(Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/functions/Function;Ljava/lang/Class;II[I[ILorg/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeInformation;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeInformation;
>       at org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream.select(PatternStream.java:96)
>       at LTMonitoringTest.main(LTMonitoringTest.java:78)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run". Also as your pattern is actually not a pattern, but a simple filter I wouldn't use CEP library at all, but just simple `filter()`.

Comment: this is the error I got by the way:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getUnaryOperatorReturnType(Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/functions/Function;Ljava/lang/Class;II[I[ILorg/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeInformation;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeInformation;
 at org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream.select(PatternStream.java:96)
 at LTMonitoringTest.main(LTMonitoringTest.java:78)

Comment: Dawid, Thanks, in this moment it is just a filter.. but It will be more complex in advance, with more than one event, and more than one pattern.

Comment: What version of Flink are you using? How do you deploy your job? Make sure the version in your job is the same as your cluster's version.

Comment: I am using 1.6.0. I am working with maven. I was checking the versions before and It is the same as in the  API for 1.6. The consumer is working properly. and the Tuple is getting the values. The problem in with the CEP library. I am following this example, which is working. I try to modify what I need, but nothing. 

https://github.com/tillrohrmann/cep-monitoring

Comment: What are you meaning by cluster version by the way?

Comment: How do you run your job?

Comment: With my IDE, IntelliJ

Comment: Make sure all of your flink dependencies point to the same version. Also make sure all of the dependencies are in compile scope (just for the IDEA), usually they have provided scope, cause they are already present in flink cluster.

Comment: Ok, I changed some dependencies to an old version (1.4) and it seams to be going forward. Now I have another error, but different. I am working on that. Any thought thou? 

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: The generic type parameters of 'Map' are missing. 
It seems that your compiler has not stored them into the .class file. 
Currently, only the Eclipse JDT compiler preserves the type information necessary to use the lambdas feature type-safely.

Comment: Ok thank you is fixed. the problem was as you said the maven dependencies. I solve the other problem, creating a new anonymous class with of Map, with similar implementation